# Office 365 Lync Startup

Tags: office365, windows-server-2012-r2, lync

I am trying to get Lync 365 to open on our users computers during Start up, as of yet i have not found a solution to my problem, i have seen some solutions for Lync Server,

We have around 20+ computers in the office, i dont want to have to sent out an email asking every one to change there settings on Lync to run on start up, it would be nice to set a GPO in Server 2012 to force a script on start up and have that start Lync 365.

i found a some script that only seem to work for Lync Server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only option to globally change settings using scripts for lync is by using the Lync server so your only option would be to change each individual computers settings during office downtime if you aren’t willing to send out the email you mentioned.

Comment: that is a shame, you cant use scripts to change settings on a Client machine running Lync 365 client.

Comment: unfortunately not, but I would assume there is a security reason behind it.